# How do I use Unix domain sockets from Java/Scala?

Tags: java, scala, jvm, unix-socket

What's the best way of using Unix domain sockets from Scala?

I've found a Java library called [JUDS](https://github.com/mcfunley/juds), but it doesn't appear to allow me to send file descriptors over the socket --- the reason I want to use Unix domain sockets in the first place.

The JUDS readme refers to a competing library called J-BUDS, but I cannot find this anywhere.

I could add the feature to JUDS myself, but I'd rather I'd rather not reinvent the wheel if it's already in a jar file elsewhere.

Comment: In the same way as you use Unix domain sockets from Java.

Comment: So how do I use them from Java? I know I can use Java libraries from Scala, I found one (JUDS) and it doesn't support the feature of Unix domain sockets I'm most interested in using.

Comment: have you tried http://code.google.com/p/junixsocket/ ? It allows things like mysql UDS's

Comment: @amir75 I wasn't aware of that, no, so thanks for the link. But it doesn't seem to support sending file descriptors over the connection.

Comment: I recommend to ask such kind of questions for Java. There are many more Java libs out there and chances are that none of the scala folks around know them.

Comment: why do you want to send FD's over the wire ?

Comment: @Tim So that a server process can read/write directly from/to the stdin/stdout/stderr of a client process.

Answer (score 1):

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html

By "file descriptors" do you mean objects of the class java.util.File?
...or C-style "FILE *"? (IIRC)

The latter would be tied to the particular instance of the OS, so I wouldn't think you would want to move that to (possibly) another machine.

Comment: By "file descriptors" I mean OS level file descriptors, typically stored in an `int` in C. I don't want to move it to a different machine, I want to move it to a different process on the same machine. Unix Domain Sockets do not support communicating between different machines, I know that.

Comment: I should have guessed JUDS was for Unix Domain Sockets.